# Swap two columns with awk

Tags: sed, awk

I try to swap two columns in a text file, the field separator is the pipe '|' sign.

I found and tried

```
awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' input_file
```

it works when the field separator is the tab.

I also tried

```
awk -F\|  '{print $2 $1 }' input_file
```

but I do not manage to specify the '|' as output field separator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the OFS, Output Field Separator. You can do it with either of these ways:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print} ' input_file
```

or

```
awk -v OFS="|" -v FS="|" ' {t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print} ' input_file
```

or ([thanks Jaypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815082/swap-two-columns-with-awk/22815130#comment34795107_22815130)!)

```
awk '{t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print}' OFS="|" FS="|" input_file
```

Comment: There is a third way as well. `awk '{t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print}' OFS="|" FS="|" input_file`

Comment: (@fedorqui "You can do it in either of these ways" is correct)

Comment: Sounds like a question for [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/). =)

Comment: @jaypal That's "traditional" not "convoluted" as it is documented awk behaviour and `-v` is (or at least was I'm not sure) a GNU awk-ism.

Comment: @EtanReisner Correct, that was just a personal opinion. Edited my comment. `:)`

Comment: @admdrew thanks!! I always learn new things in this site, you are great :)

Comment: @jaypal I added your third way. Thanks!